# DOMPDF: how to force dompdf to ignore some html page content (i.e. links, <a> tags)

Tags: html, dompdf

when I create the pdf of my page with DOMPDF, I would like to exclude something not really important or needed into the pdf file, for example the links.

Is there a way to ignore the  tags?

thanks!

Comment: Can you provide sample HTML showing what you want to exclude from the genereted PDF? Setting the display should work as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70079618/264628) should make the links not appear.

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sanitizer like [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) and configure it to disallow `a` tags.

```js
// leave all safe HTML as it is and add <a> elements to block-list
var clean = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirty, {FORBID_TAGS: ['a']});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make them disappear by using css properties

```
a { display:none; }
...
```

Comment: If possible I'd avoid to install other tools... I tried to specify display:none, but nothing changes...